# Jquery ajax implementation issue

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on the `index.php`. In the index page, my php code is generating Columns and Row(Table) in html.  I am new to Jquery.

*PHP generated table example*

```
ID | Username | Status | Action 
1     Demo        No      Install button
2     Smith       No      Install button
3     Edward      No      Install button
4     Admin       No      Install button
```

In the Action column , I've added `Install` button. So , my plan is to call `update.php` using Jquery AJAX POST when `Install` button is clicked.

Update Page Having POST variable :

```
1) id 
2) action 
3) flag
```

Now, what I've done so far.

Following code is generated by my PHP code (RAW code, for understanding)

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' id='1' value='1'>
<a href class='blue' href='' id='1'>Install</a>
<input type='hidden' name='id' id='2' value='2'>
<a href class='blue' href='' id='2'>Install</a>
<input type='hidden' name='id' id='3' value='3'>
<a href class='blue' href='' id='3'>Install</a>
<input type='hidden' name='id' id='4' value='4'>
<a href class='blue' href='' id='4'>Install</a>
```

Issue is how I can generate Jquery AJAX POST url, which will send data like

```
update.php?id=1&action=install&flag=1
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: do you know about new HTML5 data-* attributes? If not - try them, it's awesome. You don't need inputs at all for task like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say this is your button

```
<input type="button" id="my_button" value="1">

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#my_button").on('click',function () {//Your install button click
            var btInd = $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "update.php",
                data: {"id":btInd,"action":"install","flag":1}, //You need to make changes if your values will change since i have hard coded the values                      
                success: function(response) {
                  alert('Success');
                }
        }); 
});
```

Catch the request in `update.php` and do the rest.

Comment: i am generating many ID(Rows / Multiple) on the single page and on the page there will be many Install buttons. How i can deal with this issue.

Comment: Also get the id of the button clicked and pass that value in the ajax @user2345691

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {   // install button
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
           var action = "install";
            var flag = "1";      
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "update.php",
                data: {"id":id,"action":action,"flag":flag},                       
                success: function(response) {
                // do something
                }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Sample PHP

```
<?php
    include('config.php');

    if($_POST["action"]=="install"))
    {
        $id = $_POST['id']; //Here posted id
        $flag = $_POST['flag'];


    }
?>
```

Comment: i am generating many ID(Rows / Multiple) on the single page and on the page there will be many Install buttons. How i can deal with this issue.

Comment: @user2345691 yes,each install buttons have unique id,when click happens `$(this).attr("id")` in inside function will return corresponding button id so its not a problem to handle.

Comment: I've tried, can you please give me example for install button which having unique ID.

Comment: What is button and I'm using a href , what will be the name there ?        $("button").click(function () {   // install button

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'update.php',
    data: {
        id:1,
        action:xx,
        flag:ff
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

for more information see this [link](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.post( "update.php", { id: "John", action: "delete",flag :"abc" })
   .done(function( data ) {
   alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `jquery` `GET` method to post data using get ..

```
  $.get("update.php?id=1&action=install&flag=1",function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
```

or you can send data by

```
  $.get("update.php",{id=1,action=install,flag=1},function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#buttonID").live('click',function(){
   $.ajax({
            url: "../update.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id: myId, action: myAction ,flag: myflag},
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function (data) {

                alert("Great success");
            }
        });
});
```